# Xamarin android Camera2 - image preview getting stretched on 18:9 aspect ratio devices

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera2

On running the Camera2Basic in 18:9 screen aspect ratio devices, the image preview and captured image is getting stretched.

**Device camera and camera2 basic side by side:**

[image: device camera and camera2 basic side by side]

How would i resolve this while keeping the preview ratio as 1.33? I tried setting the height of the texture preview by keeping the ratio 1.33 as constant and scaling the height with width as 1080.

```
    var ratio = 1.33;
    var scaledWidth = mPreviewSize.Height;
    var scaledHeight = (int)Java.Lang.Math.Round(scaledWidth * ratio);
    mTextureView.SetAspectRatio(scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
```

But result is still the same.

Comment: What preview resolution is the application actually requesting from the camera device? (This is the value of mPreviewSize) It looks like a non-4:3 size is requested, and then drawn into a 4:3 View.

Comment: mPreviewSize is 1440*1080 which is 4:3